# How to have a before hook for specified it block in mocha?

Tags: testing, mocha.js

I want to know how to add a before hook for a specified it block in mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `before` hook and the test inside a `describe` block:

```
describe("", function () {
  before(function () {});
  it("my test", function () {});
});
```

The `before` hook set up there will be used *only* for the test in the `describe` block and won't affect any test outside of the block.